# Array declaration

Tags: command-line, scripts

How can I declare an array in Ubuntu ? I have tried the code below

```
Unix=('Zero' 'One' 'Two')

#echo -n "area2[0] = "
echo ${area2[@]}
# Aha, zero-based indexing (first element of array is [0], not [1]).

#echo -n "area2[1] = "
#echo $ {area2[1]}
```

This does not work in Ubuntu.

Comment: well it's all commented out...

Comment: Ubuntu is a distribution of an operating system. You could declare an array in Ubuntu using C/Java/Perl/... bash is the programming language you are talking about here.

Answer (score 5):

If you called/named your array `Unix`, why do you use `area2`?!? Or did you declared before this array named `area2`? Try this:

```
Unix=('Zero' 'One' 'Two')

echo "Unix = ${Unix[@]}"
echo "Unix[0] = ${Unix[0]}"
echo "Unix[1] = ${Unix[1]}"
```

And please read some documentation about [Arrays in Bash](http://tldp.org/LDP/abs/html/arrays.html).

Answer (score 2):

I will give you a full example:

```
#!/bin/bash    
array=("first item" "second item" "third" "item")

echo "Number of items in original array: ${#array[*]}" 

for ix in ${!array[*]} 
do
    printf "   %s\n" "${array[$ix]}" 
done 

arr=(${array[*]}) 
echo "After unquoted expansion: ${#arr[*]}" 

for ix in ${!arr[*]} 
do
    printf "   %s\n" "${arr[$ix]}" 
done 

arr=("${array[*]}") 
echo "After * quoted expansion: ${#arr[*]}" 

for ix in ${!arr[*]} 
do
    printf "   %s\n" "${arr[$ix]}" 
done 

arr=("${array[@]}") 
echo "After @ quoted expansion: ${#arr[*]}" 

for ix in ${!arr[*]}     
do
    printf "   %s\n" "${arr[$ix]}" 
done
```

I hope it helps.

Comment: What are the the reasons for `printf` and for `${!arr[*]}`?

Comment: Just demonstrating how arrays work in Bash.

Comment: I mean: why `printf "   %s\n" "${arr[$ix]}"` instead of a more simple `echo "   ${arr[$ix]}"`? And why `for ix in ${!arr[*]}` instead of a more intuitive `for x in "${arr[@]}"` (so that you can write `echo "   $x"`)?

Comment: Just formatting the output. ;)